# I want to change text background color while selecting text that should also run in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change text background color while selecting text that should also run in safari browser....
The code should be coded with javascript and html.
Anyone have the code of that?

Comment: Do you mean: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection

Comment: Thanks Alex..But I want to do that with Javascript, not with the CSS.

Comment: This question shows no effort on your part, this site is for assistance, not for asking for code.

Comment: Sorry digwig..But I tried many times and had searched for many times. After that i asked for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I have the code but not with javascript . Sorry for that - an equally good result is yielded with CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) .

We make use of pseudo class called "  selection ". So the code goes like this :

```
          ::selection {
           color: red;
           background: yellow;
           }
```

For more information : [Visit this site](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp)

This is a css3 pseudo class and will work only in browsers supporting CSS3 and is not supported in IE < 9 but is a great way to highlight selected text. in supported browsers.

Comment: Please vote the answer if good , because other people will get benefited too .